# C# conditional formatting excel

Tags: c#, excel, formatting, excel-2007, excel-interop

In my project I have code that formats the cell's back color based on a cell value condition like this:

```
//if value is 1 than colorIndex is 3;
Excel.FormatCondition condition = colorRange.FormatConditions.Add(
    Type: Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlTextString, 
    Operator: Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlEqual,
    Formula1: "=1");
condition5.Interior.ColorIndex = 3;
```

This condition works fine, but the condition in the following code does not work:

```
//if value is Red Color than colorIndex is 3;
Excel.FormatCondition condition = colorRange.FormatConditions.Add(
    Type: Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlTextString, 
    Operator: Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlEqual,
    Formula1: "=Red Color");
condition5.Interior.ColorIndex = 3;
```

The error messgage I receive is "Incorrect Parameter"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what are you attempting to do with the second code block?  what is it that should be red?  As the code reads right now, it appears that you're testing whether or not the cell contains the literal "Red Color", and I'm guessing that the "Incorrect Parameter" error is thrown because "Red Color" is not properly referenced as a string.  I'm also guessing that you're not intending to test for the literal "Red Color" and that, instead, you're trying to check whether or not the ForeColor of the cell is Red.  Am I close?

Comment: yes, I'd like to determine the cell color by certain literal, it works perfectlly for fiirst code block, it determine by numbers although the datatype is string. but second block just not work and pop-up the  error msg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the errors comes from the fact that the Formula1 parameter you are passing is a formula. This means that  it should be written like the formulas that you manually write in the Excel cells. This means that when you write "Red color" as your parameter, Excel tries to convert it to a Formula, but the syntax is wrong and it gives you the error.

You can try to put just "=Red" (without the color part of the string), and it wouldn't give you an error, but it wouldn't work anyway, because it would compare the value in your cell with the one contained in the cell named Red (and I suppose you haven't such a cell in your worksheet).

The solution is to put " around you string in this way:

```
Excel.FormatCondition condition = colorRange.FormatConditions.Add(
    Type: Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlTextString, 
    Operator: Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlEqual,
    Formula1: "=\"Red Color\"");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this out. This code provides me solution

```
 Excel.FormatCondition condition = colorRange.FormatConditions.Add(
     XlFormatConditionType.xlCellValue, 
     XlFormatConditionOperator.xlEqual,
     "=\"Red Color\"", 
     Type.Missing, 
     Type.Missing, 
     Type.Missing, 
     Type.Missing, 
     Type.Missing);
```